# C++ method name and enum class name conflicts

Tags: c++

I have a class which has a "*type*" method and an enum class "*type*" in it. I want to make both named "type".

```
class proxy {
public:
    enum class type { direct, http };
    enum type type() const { return type_; }
private:
    enum type type_ = type::direct;
};
```

When I compiles it, I got the following error:

```
 error: ‘type’ is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
 enum type type_ = type::direct;
```

I know that's because my type method hide the enum class type. Is it possible to solve this in C++?

Comment: _"Is it possible to solve this in C++?"_ Of course, use different names.

Comment: Or namespace one of them.

Comment: Works for me. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Can't reproduce, [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/oTvJOP).

Comment: @n.m. It doesn't compile for me in VS 2015. "C3431 'type': a scoped enumeration cannot be redeclared as an unscoped enumeration." (on both the line for the type() declaration and the type_ declaration)

Comment: I think it's just confusing (to both the user of your class and the compiler) to have a method named like a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For VS 2015, this compiles for me:

```
class proxy {
public:
    enum class type { direct, http };
    enum class type type() const { return type_; }
private:
    enum class type type_ = type::direct;
};
```

You just have to add the "class" keyword in since it's a scoped enum.

Usage for VS:

```
proxy p;
enum class proxy::type var = p.type();
```

Your original solution compiles for gcc 6.3 and clang 3.9.1:

```
class proxy {
public:
    enum class type { direct, http };
    enum type type() const { return type_; }
private:
    enum type type_ = type::direct;
};
```

Usage for clang and gcc:

```
proxy p;
enum proxy::type var = p.type();
```

For gcc 5.4, you can typedef the enum in the private section of the class.

Comment: No, this doesn't compiles for me. Got these errors:   
warning: elaborated-type-specifier for a scoped enum must not use the ‘class’ keyword
     enum class type type() const { return type_; }
     ^
warning: elaborated-type-specifier for a scoped enum must not use the ‘class’ keyword
     enum class type type_ = type::direct;
     ^
error: ‘type’ is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
     enum class type type_ = type::direct;

Comment: Ok, well then we need to know what compiler you're using @ChrisXJZhu

Comment: Does not work with gcc 4.9 because of name conflict between the enum class and the function.

Comment: @BenjaminT Interesting. I might leave this answer around for VS users. My usefulness has run out since I don't have access to a gcc compiler right now (ok I do, but it's 3 am and I don't want to ssh in). Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @BenjaminT If you have the time, can you verify my g++ 5.4.0 solution?

Comment: Neither clang nor g++ accept this. OTOH both clang 3.9.1 and gcc 6.1.3 (i.e. reasonably up to date) accept `enum type type()` and `enum type type_` without the "class".

Comment: @n.m. I was just discovering with godbolt.org that gcc gives warnings with the class and takes them away when you remove the class. I'll update.

Comment: Sorry it was a warning with g++, but an error with clang.

Comment: gcc 5.4.0 doesn't accept with or without the `class` keyword.

Comment: @n.m. Ha, I'm an idiot. The code I put in for clang and gcc (while it compiles) is the exact same as OP's code. And yes, gcc 5.4 is not compiling for me either. I have to typedef the type in the private section to get it to work in gcc 5.4

Comment: VC seems to be in the wrong. 7.1.6.3 says 'elaborated-type-specifier' is never 'enum class anything'.

Comment: @MillieSmith, Thanks! I tried clang++ 3.8. My original code did compile. Sigh, it looks like the solutions are compiler-dependent. I have to not use enum class.

Comment: @ChrisXJZhu you're welcome. You can do whatever you want of course, but I would think that the benefits of a scoped enum would outweigh the benefits of naming the function and the enum the same thing. @ n.m. interesting. Thanks for the input with the standard.

Comment: Interestingly, this still works with Visual C++ 2017 (at least with the RC I have installed) and the `/permissive-` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
class proxy {
public:
    enum class type { direct, http };
    type getType() const { return type_; }
private:
    type type_ = type::direct;
};
```

- Replace `enum type` by `type`, you do not need `enum` when using an enum type in C++.
- Rename the function `type()`, it conflicts with the enum name.